# Xamarin - какие библиотеки использовать для написания сканера bluetooth и wifi?

Tags: c#, xamarin, wifi, bluetooth

Мне необходимо написать кроссплатформенное приложение для поиска устройств bluetooth и сетей WiFi с выводом информации об устройствах и сетях. Писал такие приложения на windows forms с помощью библиотек [ManagedWifi](https://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) и [InTheHand.Net.Personal](https://32feet.codeplex.com/), но написать с помощью этих библиотек на xamarin не получается.

Пробовал написать, пока что, только скан wifi, при компиляции выдает такую ошибку:

> MCG0004:InternalAssert Assert Failed: Unexpected inline array element
>   type. during [UNKNOWN]    MyProject.UWP

Возможно ли вообще написать такое приложение с одной библиотекой для всех устройств, или для каждого устройства нужно свою библиотеку использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта "верны".
Надо задействовать реализацию внутренних классов системы.
Андройд https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/Android.Bluetooth/
iOS https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/MonoTouch.CoreBluetooth/

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Net.Wifi.WifiManager/
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/Android.Net.Wifi/

Либо ищите готовые плагины(тут на свой вкус).
https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/BluetoothLEExplorer

https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le

но тут есть проблема в том, что Apple не предоставляет API для вывода списка доступных Wi-Fi(только текущий статус). Так, что придется это наверное исключить.